# Google sheet count occurrences based on another cell references value

Tags: google-sheets

I want to do a some what simple count, but I cant figure out how.

I want to count all players where G colum is equal to a given value

I expect to count for example: "Naxxramas 25" and get the count 4 from the data below

I created a sheet with sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19T80MC9Lpi4idyZbxKiqu_Ydc6D4WLp2E8tkIMCd7dM/edit#gid=0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer take a look [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D9gVJqmYb_Uz8N3S8-tVtdE69n4-j6-t46GkswBS9ZY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do so. Try following the pattern of this [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) formula

```
=QUERY({B2:B7,G2:G7;C2:C7,G2:G7},
          "select count(Col1) where Col2='Naxxramas 25'
           label count(Col1) '' ",0)
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Take a look at [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D9gVJqmYb_Uz8N3S8-tVtdE69n4-j6-t46GkswBS9ZY/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=COUNTA(FILTER($B$2:$F$5,$G$2:$G$5=A9))
```

[image]